# Passing variable to permission class in DRF gives an error

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to use the following permission class in many apps in the project, the only change needed is the model class that user data is checked from.

Permission class:

```
class IsAuthorOrForbidden(permissions.BasePermission):
"""
Check if the requesting user the author or not
"""
def __init__(self, modelClass):
    self.modelClass = modelClass

def has_permission(self, request, view):
    # get the needed model instance or 404 if not available
    instance = get_object_or_404(self.modelClass, pk=view.kwargs['pk'])
    # Check if the requesting user is the author
    if instance.user == request.user:
        return True
    return False
```

The permission class in the view class:

```
class TextNoteGenerateShareKeyAPIView(generics.UpdateAPIView):
"""
Generate a new text note share key
"""
authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication,)
permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,
                      IsAuthorOrForbidden(modelClass=TextNote))
...
```

When I run the tests, i get this error:

> return [permission() for permission in self.permission_classes]
> TypeError: 'IsAuthorOrForbidden' object is not callable

Is it possible to do it like this or should I write this permission class in every app in my project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [object level permission](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#custom-permissions):

```
class IsAuthorOrForbidden(permissions.BasePermission):

    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        return obj.user == request.user
```

and add it to the view like this:

```
permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,
              IsAuthorOrForbidden)
```

#### Explanation on why the error is occurring

To understand the error, you need to see the implementation of [`get_permissions`](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/bb133522efaf6ce3ae8fdf1dec6cd79566cfd166/rest_framework/views.py#L278) method in GitHub source code:

```
#copy pasted from GitHub
def get_permissions(self):
    """
    Instantiates and returns the list of permissions that this view requires.
    """
    return [permission() for permission in self.permission_classes]
```

Here it is making a list of objects from `self.permission_classes`, meaning `permission_classes` are suppose to have Class, not objects.

You are adding a `IsAuthorOrForbidden` object to the permission classes, where you need to add the class. If you want to put a override, then it should be done here:

```
class TextNoteGenerateShareKeyAPIView(generics.UpdateAPIView):

    def get_permissions(self):
        return [IsAuthenticated(), IsAuthorOrForbidden(modelClass=TextNote)]
```

But this is a hackish solution where solution in the original answer is the proper way to implement in DRF.

Comment: @rudda That's true, I can do this and it will work (I'll update this case to your solution), but there are other cases different than this example, and providing the model name to the permission class will really help in less coding and more readability, If you or anyone can help understanding why the problem is occurring would be perfect.

Comment: I have added an explanation on why the error is occurring.

Answer (score 0):

For those who are using "viewsets" and want to allow only the author to access the content/items you can simply use a mixin like below and use that mixin in whichever viewsets that requires.

```
#  mixin
class FilterByUserMixin:
    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        queryset = super().get_queryset(*args, **kwargs)
        return queryset.filter(user=self.request.user)

#  viewsets
class WhateverViewSet(FilterByUserMixin, viewsets.ModelViewSet):
```

Comment: btw this is for someone who is having `REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    "DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES": ["rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated"],}`

Answer (score 0):

One way to make the OP's code work is to add a `__call__` method to the permission class that just returns the object.

```py
class IsAuthorOrForbidden(permissions.BasePermission):
    
    def __call__(self):
        return self
```

This will avoid the TypeError that was being thrown when the `permission_classes` are being instantiated into objects, by simply returning the object when it is called. This allows for passing arguments to the `permission_classes` like the OP wanted.

Answer (score 0):

tks, fix my issue

```
class PermissionForChatGPT(permissions.BasePermission):
"""
Custom permission to only allow owners of an object to edit it.
"""
def __init__(self, codename):
    self.codename = codename

def __call__(self):
    return self

def has_permission(self, request, view):
    if(request.user.is_anonymous == True):
         return False
    return request.user.has_perm(self.codename)
```